# Plot y, x and t

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {y[x]^2 - (2/13)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + 1/1000/x^2 - 7/10] + 19/39000/x^2 -7/10 == 0}; 
sol = DSolve[eqns, y, x]; 
Plot[y[x]^2 /. sol[[1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {a/Subscript[a, 0], "E"}]
Plot[y[x]^2 /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {a/Subscript[a, 0], "E"}]
Plot[y[x]^2 /. sol[[3]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {a/Subscript[a, 0], "E"}]
Plot[y[x]^2 /. sol[[4]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, AxesLabel -> {a/Subscript[a, 0], "E"}]
```

Now if I have this expression for `y[x] = y0 * Derivative[1][x][t]/x[t]` and `y0 = 71`and  how can I plot $y$ vs $t$ and $x$ vs $t$?

Comment: Where did you define `x[t]`?

Comment: I didn't define it yet but I want to know how to introduce this to my equation?

Comment: What is the meaning of new parameter `t`?

Comment: t isn't parameter it is variable which means the time

Comment: Ok , but in your code I only see `x,y` . That's why you should show the context with `t `

Comment: I don't see a need for the first DSolve.  It's just an equation in y[x].  Could have used Solve[eqn,y[x]]

Answer (score 1):

Using the first solution of y[x] we may write an diff. equation for x[t]:

```
y1[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[1]];
DSolve[{y1[x[t]] == x'[t]/71}, x[t], t]
```

[image]

MMA can not find a closed form analytical solution. We may try to find a numerical solution. For this we need to assume an initial value, say e.g. x[0]==1 and a start and end time, e.g. 0 and 10. With this we get x[t]:

```
x1[t_] = x[t] /. 
  NDSolve[{y1[x[t]] == 100 x'[t]/71, x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[x1[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

From x[t] we get y[x[t]]:

```
Plot[y1[x1[t]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For all other solutions to x[t] we proceed analogously.

Comment: Thank you this is very good approach

Answer (score 1):

Problem is a bit ambiguous I think and setup has changed since initial posting.  Here's my analysis of the current version:  We are given the expression:

$$
-\frac{2}{13} \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1000 x^2}+y(x)^2-\frac{7}{10}} y(x)+\frac{19}{39000 x^2}+y(x)^2-\frac{7}{10}=0
$$
with the stipulation:

> Now if I have this expression for y[x] = y0 * Derivative[1][x][t]/x[t]
> and y0 = 71and how can I plot y vs t and x vs t?

which I interpret as $x=x(t)$ and $y(x)=71\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}$ then:

```
eqn2 = {y[x]^2 - (2/13)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*
      Sqrt[y[x]^2 + 1/1000/x^2 - 7/10] + 19/39000/x^2 - 7/10 == 
    0} /. {y[x] -> 72 x'[t]/x[t], x -> x[t]}
```

produces:
$$
\frac{5184 x'(t)^2}{x(t)^2}-\frac{144 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{5184 x'(t)^2}{x(t)^2}+\frac{1}{1000 x(t)^2}-\frac{7}{10}} x'(t)}{13 x(t)}+\frac{19}{39000 x(t)^2}-\frac{7}{10}=0
$$

Letting for example $x_0=1$, and solving:

```
x0 = 1;
sol = NDSolve[Append[eqn2, x[0] == x0], x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

produces four solutions for $x(t)$.  Using Bob's code above

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[x[t] /. sol],
  {t, 0, 10},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}],
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, x})]
```

produces four plots for $x(t)$:

[image]

but solving for $y[x]$ in the first expression:

```
theY = y[x] /. 
  Solve[y[x]^2 - (2/13)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*
      Sqrt[y[x]^2 + 1/1000/x^2 - 7/10] + 19/39000/x^2 - 7/10 == 0, 
   y[x]]
```

produces four solutions for $y(x)$.  So that $y(t)$ should be 8 solutions:

```
 pTable = Table[
      Plot[theY[[i]] /. x -> Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}],
      {i, 1, Length@theY}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Make the dependence on `t` explicit in `eqns`

```
eqns = {y[x]^2 - (2/13)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*Sqrt[y[x]^2 + 1/1000/x^2 - 7/10] + 
     19/39000/x^2 - 7/10 == 0} /. x -> x[t]

(* {-(7/10) + 19/(39000 x[t]^2) + y[x[t]]^2 - 
   2/13 Sqrt[3] y[x[t]] Sqrt[-(7/10) + 1/(1000 x[t]^2) + y[x[t]]^2] == 0} *)
```

Substituting for the definition of `y[x[t]]`

```
y0 = 100; x0 = 71;

eqns2 = eqns /. y[x[t]] :> y0*x'[t]/x0

(* {-(7/10) + 19/(39000 x[t]^2) + (10000 Derivative[1][x][t]^2)/5041 - 
   200/923 Sqrt[3]
     Derivative[1][x][t] Sqrt[-(7/10) + 1/(1000 x[t]^2) + (
     10000 Derivative[1][x][t]^2)/5041] == 0} *)
```

Assuming that `x[0] == x0`, the solution for `x[t]` is

```
sol = NDSolve[Append[eqns2, x[0] == x0],
   x, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Plotting `x` versus `t`

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[x[t] /. sol],
 {t, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, x})]
```

[image]

Plotting `y` versus `t`

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[y0*x'[t]/x0 /. sol],
 {t, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {t, y})]
```

[image]

Plotting `y` versus `x`

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y0*x'[t]/x0} /. sol],
 {t, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .5}],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x[t], y[t]})]
```

[image]

Comment: I changed little bit this answer but seems not working?!

Clear["Global`*"]
eqn2 = {y[x]^2 - (1/52)*Sqrt[3]*y[x]*
       Sqrt[y[x]^2 + (x/x0)^-2/1000 - (69/100)] + ((49 (x/x0)^-2)/
        100000) - (69/100) == 0} /. {y[x] -> x'[t]/(H0 x[t]), 
    x -> x[t]};
H0 = 71; x0 = 70;
sol = NDSolve[Append[eqn2, x[1] == x0], x, {t, 0, 10}]

Comment: Your revised equation needs to be evaluated with arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision. Add the option `WorkingPrecision->15` to the `NDSolve`. However, the solution does not cover the full range of `t`. Look at the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction`s or `sol[[All, 1, -1, 1]]`